# How to set the X-Google-Original-From header in Alpine (Pine) email?

Tags: command-line, email, imap, gmail, alpine-mail

*Why the random down-vote?  At least say what the problem with the question is.*

---

I'm using `Gmail` and `Alpine` for e-mail with `IMAP`.  Mail sent from `Alpine` has this field:

```
X-Google-Original-From: foo <foo@gmail.com>
```

whereas it should be my `Gmail` address, of course.

where can I explicitly set this value with `Alpine`?

[see](https://alpineapp.email/alpine/alpine-info/misc/headers.html):

Configuring other Headers
If you want to configure the value of a header that does not appear in the above list, you will need to edit your configuration file. The way to do this is by going to the configuration screen and adding the following text to the Customized Headers option:

Customized Headers = Header_name: Value

The Value part above is not required, nor is the colon after the Header_name. Here are some examples of possible additions you may want to consider

```
Customized Headers = From: "Your Name" <email@address.com>,
                  Reply-To: "Your Name" <another@address.org>,
                  Control:,
                  Status:,
                  X-Status:
```

But this is an "x header" value.

---

new info:

Seems like setting "use sender instead of x-x sender" helps with forcing Google to use the gmail address.

This is manually entering a full e-mail into the "from" header when composing.  Perhaps there's a way to autopopulate that?

Still testing how that works.

Answer (score 0):

Sorta works:

```
X-Google-Original-From: nicholas <nicholas@gmail.com>
Date: Mon, 4 Dec 2023 23:11:59 -0800 (PST)
To: foo@example.com
Subject: ping
Message-ID: <5b851c90-edfc-6d3f-8ac5-5735f5c77744@gmail.com>
X-Google-Original-From: saunders.nicholas@gmail.com
```

Except that it shows up twice, and only once correctly.  From M S C for the configuration:

```
Initial Keystroke List            = <No Value Set>                                                                                                                                                         
Default Composer Headers          = <Empty Value>                                                                                                                                                          
Customized Headers                = X-Google-Original-From:saunders.nicholas@gmail.com                                                                                                                     
Viewer Headers                    = <Empty Value>                                                                                                                                                          
Viewer Margin Left                = <No Value Set: using "0">                                                                                                                                              
Viewer Margin Right               = <No Value Set: using "4">                                                                                                                                              
Quote Suppression Threshold       = <No Value Set: using "0">
```

Is Pine putting this field on there, or does Google add that when sending?  Because if Google adds that to the header when sending not sure how to change it.

Comment: I think Google adds that header because your actual Gmail address is different from your From and from what you add as X-Google-Original-From

Comment: yeah, I'm monkeying in the pinerc to see if I can change it.  Possibly it's getting picked up by some spam filters so want it to be consistent.

Comment: seems related to x-x-sender @MikaFeiler I'm thinking